# iOS: User purchases points, how should I track points after purchase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, shopify

Any feedback on this question would be extremely helpful. I've built an app that allows my users to purchase "points". Once a user selects the number of points they'd like to purchase by selecting a tableview cell, they are taken to the viewcontroller that completes the purchase (collects cc details, etc). I'm using Shopify's Mobile Buy SDK to orchestrate this.

Once a user's checkout is successful (let's say my user bought 30 points), how can I go about displaying that number in a label AFTER the purchase is made?

**In short:** **I'm looking to have my code display the number of points a user currently has after a purchase.**

**Extra background:** My users log in to my app through Drupal (I'm using the Drupal iOS SDK). I'm almost wondering if there's a way for me to use the Shopify module somehow to track this?

See some of my code below for reference.

**Tableviewcontroller.m** (user selects number of points to purchase, points are added to cart, user is pushed to checkout viewcontroller)

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"PointsCell";

            PointsCell *cell = (PointsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PointsCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            }


            BUYProduct *productsbuy = self.products[indexPath.row];
            cell.productLabel.text = productsbuy.title;

            BUYProduct *productDescription = self.products[indexPath.row];
            cell.productDescrip.text = productDescription.htmlDescription;


            BUYProduct *pointValues = self.products[indexPath.row];
            BUYProductVariant *variant = pointValues.variants.firstObject;

            cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", variant.price];

            return cell;

        }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // BUYCart *cart = [[BUYCart alloc] init];

    BUYProduct *product = self.products[indexPath.row];

    BUYProductVariant *variant = [product.variants firstObject];


    if (!self.cart) {
        self.cart = [BUYCart singleton];
    }
    [self.cart addVariant:variant];

        NSLog(@"%@",variant);


    PayViewController *checkOutVC = [[PayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:checkOutVC animated:YES];


}
```

**CheckoutViewController.m** (user enters details, taps button for purchase and checkout is complete)

```
- (IBAction)purchasePoints:(id)sender {


    BUYCreditCard *creditCard = [[BUYCreditCard alloc] init];
    creditCard.number = self.cardNumber.text;
    creditCard.expiryMonth = self.expMonth.text;
    creditCard.expiryYear = self.expYear.text;
    creditCard.cvv = self.csvNumber.text;
    creditCard.nameOnCard = self.fullcardName.text;

    BUYClient *client = [BUYClient singleton];

    [client storeCreditCard:creditCard checkout:self.checkout completion:^(BUYCheckout *returnedCheckout, NSString *paymentSessionId, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            self.checkout = returnedCheckout;

             [self tryCompleteCheckout];

        } else {

        }
    }];


}
```

Comment: Are the points associated with an account on your server? Youmshoukdmstore the balance in that account in your server. If they are only in the local device then you can use keychain. Are the points used to access features or content in your app? If so you will get rejected for not using Apples in-app purchase system.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey Paul - thanks for the feedback re: Apple's in-app purchase system. Users will use the points to trade services with one and other, however no content or features are locked as a result of not purchasing points (users could use the app completely free if they choose). Thoughts?

Comment: @Gordonium Suggestion: just update your answer.

Comment: @Brittany hello plz can you help me in add to cart Functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is pretty easy. what you need to do is

- check what points the user had selected
- store that info in NSUserDefaults
- if the purchase was successful convert that value to an int and add to another NSUserDefaults
- Use that info to display that where ever you like, UILabel etc

Sample code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// ... your code 
   //i assume this variant has user points?
    BUYProductVariant *variant = [product.variants firstObject];

NSString *pointsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", variant];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pointsStr forKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

now in your successful completion of purchase do this

```
- (IBAction)purchasePoints:(id)sender {


    //... your code


    [client storeCreditCard:creditCard checkout:self.checkout completion:^(BUYCheckout *returnedCheckout, NSString *paymentSessionId, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
//purchase was successful
NSString *pointsStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];

//incase he already had points from some previous purchase
NSString *totalUsePoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"totalUsePoints"];

int pointsInt = [pointsStr intVal];
int totalUsePointsInt = [totalUsePoints intVal];

totalUsePointsInt = totalUsePointsInt + pointsInt;

NSString *totalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", totalUsePointsInt];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:totalStr forKey:@"totalUsePoints"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
```

Comment: I absolutely adore you for putting this together - thank you so much. I'll start implementing this now and let you know how it goes! Quick question though: If I'm saving to NSUserDefaults, and a user logs in with their username and password on a different device, the points are lost? No?

Comment: unfortunately yes, the points are local to the device in a regular NSUserDefaults. But having said that google iCloud Key-Value Data tutorials. They store the values the same way as NSUserdefaults does and of course the best part is that the value in that variable is shared across all devices. I would only store totalUsePoints in iCloud. Happy coding

Comment: Hey Sam - awesome, thank you. So just to clarify: If I go that route, users will be able to retrieve their saved data from any device they have that's hooked up to their iCloud account?

Comment: you bet. I just implemented such feature not long ago in my latest app

Comment: Awesome. Love this. Though I do wonder long term if we plan on rolling the app out on Android and what not. That said, Apple tends to smile on those using their bells and whistles, lol.

Comment: Implemented your above in my app, used iCloud Key Value Storage. Unreal. Thank you so much. Great answer.